# Why :hover does not work for the specified class

Tags: html, css, hyperlink, hover

I have the following html code:

```
 <a class="deletelink" onclick="return !deleteitem('delete.php')" href="delete.php"> Delete Item </a>
```

with the following css:

```
a.deletelink:hover, 
a.deletelink:active { 
    background-color: #F00; 
    color:#FF0;
}

a.deletelink:visited,
a.deletelink:link {
    line-height:5em;
    width: 5em;
    text-align: center;
    margin:2em;
    display: block;
    font-weight: bold;
    color:#F00;
    background-color:#639;
    padding: 0.5em;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

but the color of the link will not change when mouse moves over it. Could you guess what is wrong here?

thanks

Comment: The link is always 'visited' to you as a developer, so those styles overwrite the earlier `:hover` styles.

Comment: thank you all, the problem solved by changing the order of hover and link as you suggested.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that `:hover` must come after `:link` and `:visited` pseudo classes, otherwise it won't affect the element.

```css
a.deletelink:visited ,a.deletelink:link{ /* ... */ }
a.deletelink:hover, a.deletelink:active { /* ... */ }
```

From **[MDN page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:hover)**:

> This style may be overridden by any other link-related pseudo-classes,
>   that is :link, :visited, and :active, appearing in subsequent rules.
>
> In order to style appropriately links, you need to put the `:hover`
>   rule after the `:link` and `:visited` rules but before the `:active` one, as
>   defined by the LVHA-order: `:link` — `:visited` — `:hover` — `:active`.

Answer (score 3):

Just change the order of hover behaviour:

```
 a.deletelink:visited ,a.deletelink:link{line-height:5em;width: 5em;text-align: center; margin:2em;display: block;font-weight: bold;color:#F00;background-color:#639;padding: 0.5em;text-decoration: none;}
a.deletelink:hover, a.deletelink:active{ background-color: #F00; color:#FF0;}
```

[working demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/w2g4pzfv/)

---

:hover must be used after `:link , :visited`

---

You should follow the `LoVeHAte` formula where L denotes Link, V denotes Visited, H denotes Hover and A denotes Active.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use `hover` after `:link` and `:visited` properties :

```
a.deletelink:visited,
a.deletelink:link {
    line-height:5em;
    width: 5em;
    text-align: center;
    margin:2em;
    display: block;
    font-weight: bold;
    color:#F00;
    background-color:#639;
    padding: 0.5em;
    text-decoration: none;
}

a.deletelink:hover, 
a.deletelink:active{ 
    background-color: #F00; 
    color:#FF0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
a.deletelink:active{ background-color: #F00; color:#FF0;}
a.deletelink:hover { background-color: #F00;color: #FF0;}
a.deletelink:visited {line-height:5em;width: 5em;text-align: center; margin:2em;display:     block;font-weight: bold;color:#F00;background-color:#639;padding: 0.5em;text-decoration: none;}
.deletelink {line-height:5em;width: 5em;text-align: center; margin:2em;display: block;font-weight: bold;color:#F00;background-color:#639;padding: 0.5em;text-decoration: none;}
```

that should do it for you