# Anchor tag not working on hover css

Tags: html, css

I'm getting this strange issue, for some reason my anchor tags doesn't work on hover or active state.

```
<span class="subHeaders">
 <a href="" />First </a>
</span>

<span class="subHeaders">
 <a href="" />Second </a>
</span>

<span class="subHeaders">
 <a href="" />third </a>
 </span>


 // css
 .subHeaders a:link {
  text-decoration: none;
 }

.subHeaders a:active {
  color: yellow;
}
.subHeaders a:hover{
   cursor: pointer;
   color: red;
 }
```

subheaders a:link class only works, hover and active don't.

Comment: Your html is invalid.

Comment: `<a href="" />` closes the link element without it having any content.

Comment: Also follow the LVHA-order: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25620839/why-hover-does-not-work-for-the-specified-class/25620903#25620903

Answer (score 3):

You had an error in your HTML you used `<a/></a>` and you should use `<a></a>`. Use this:

```
<span class="subHeaders">
 <a href="" >First </a>
</span>

<span class="subHeaders">
 <a href="" >Second </a>
</span>

<span class="subHeaders">
 <a href="" >third </a>
 </span>
```

Answer (score 2):

Remove the `/`

```
<span class="subHeaders">
    <a href="">third </a>
</span>
```

Also check that no other styles in your CSS are conflicting.

Answer (score 1):

add !important;

```
<span class="subHeaders">
     <a href="" />First </a>
    </span>

    <span class="subHeaders">
     <a href="" />Second </a>
    </span>

    <span class="subHeaders">
     <a href="" />third </a>
     </span>

     .subHeaders a:link {
      text-decoration: none;
     }

    .subHeaders a:active {
      color: yellow !important;
    }
    .subHeaders a:hover{
       cursor: pointer;
       color: red !important;
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your a tags are closed in place with
a /, use a only

Answer (score 0):

you don't need to close the first part of your anchor tags like that.

Here's a working update for you: http://jsfiddle.net/tyhzh8gt/1/

```
<span class="subHeaders">
  <a href="" >First </a>
</span>

<span class="subHeaders">
  <a href="" >Second </a>
</span>

<span class="subHeaders">
  <a href="" >third </a>
</span>
```